Ubuntu 24.04 remote desktop shuts down opening some apps
I've installed a fresh Ubuntu 24.04 installation with all the drivers working properly. The propietary desktop remote acces seems to work just perfectly in appearance...but, if it closes the conection when opening most of the apps. I'm connecting to it via VPN and the ports are correctly opened. As you see in this video, terminal works perfectly and firefox works too. None of the others work. If I open nautilus or config, they just don't show up and nothing happens. If I open edge, darktable or any other, the connection closes.
May be something related with the default wayland desktop?
https://res.cloudinary.com/dchhykqlb/video/upload/f_auto:video,q_auto/zhfttljqrjzh2vvkkno0

I am having the same problem on a freshly installed Ubuntu 24.04. Applications like Firefox work but if I try to open "Settings" or "Welcome to Ubuntu" no window is shown even though the icon beneath it is active.

If I try to start "nautilus" from terminal it won't work either.

Same problem with NVIDIA drivers. If I turn on nouveau, Ubuntu remote login works well. Look like it's driver's problem

Ubuntu remote login works perfectly. There issue here is that some apps works while others dont. Terminal works, firefox works, nautilus dont, edge dont...
